# strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'numpy.float64'> (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning

Good Morning,

I am incurring this problem 'strptime() argument 0 must be str, not '.

I have followed number of answers in previous posts but this problem is still there.

My date format is in timestamp.

[image: Code can be seen in this attached picture.]

Kindly assist me in this mean.

Thank you.

Best regards,
Waqar Ali

Comment: Please do not post code as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue goes to your data class within Pandas.  The data you are referencing is returning as `float64` instead of a `str` type required by strptime().

Check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html?highlight=numpy%20float64) for more information on your data structure within numpy.

Since you didn't give us any data to reference we can't really tell you why it is returning as that type.

Comment: Thank you GiraffeMan91, I am using these: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time